# Why does calling an overloaded constructor cause a call of the default constructor?

Tags: c++

My C++ Programm always calls too more constructors than i intended to. It should create an edge, which then automatically creates two nodes by the string-input of the overloaded edge-constructor.

But it first calls the default-constructor of the node objects and then the overloaded self-defined constructor. The destructors do not delete the default nodes immediately. That causes an error in my program.

The problem is that the program should count the amount of objects and allocate an appropriate ID related to the amount of objects.

Compiler-Output

```
Default-Constructor
Default-Constructor
Overload-Constructor
ID: 1 numInstances: 2
Destructor
Overload-Constructor
ID: 2 numInstances: 1
Destructor
Edge:  -> Node_0002

Destructor
Destructor
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Here is a snippet for you to see the code which most likely causes the error:

main.cpp

```
int main() {
    Edge e1 = Edge("1", "2");
    std::cout << "Edge: " << e1.toString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

node.hpp

```
double Node::numInstances = 0;
Node::Node()
{
    numInstances++;
    cout << "Default-Constructor" << endl;
    double idNumber = numInstances;
    m_id = setUpIdString(idNumber);
}

Node::Node(string id)
{
    double idNumber = getNumberFromString(id);
    cout << "Overload-Constructor" << endl;
    cout << "ID: " << idNumber << " numInstances: " << numInstances << endl;
    if (idNumber > numInstances) {
        numInstances++;
        m_id = setUpIdString(idNumber);
    }
}

Node::~Node()
{
    numInstances--;
    cout << "Destructor" << endl;
}
```

edge.cpp

```
Edge::Edge(string src, string dst)
{
    m_srcNode = Node(src);
    m_dstNode = Node(dst);
}
```

EDIT:

node.hpp

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node();
    Node(string id);
    ~Node();
    string getId();

private:
    string m_id;
    static double numInstances;
};
```

edge.hpp

```
class Edge
{
public:
    Edge(Node& rSrc, Node& rDst);
    Edge(string src, string dst);
    string toString();
    Node& getSrcNode();
    Node& getDstNode();

private:
    Node m_srcNode;
    Node m_dstNode;
};
```

Comment: You need to post the class definitions of `Node` and `Edge` for us to be able to answer this question.

Comment: `Edge` constructor first default-constructs `m_srcNode` and `m_dstNode`, and then later assigns to these default-constructed instances. Most likely, you are looking for `Edge::Edge(string src, string dst) : m_srcNode(src), m_dstNode(dst) {}`. Read about constructor initializer list in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: `Edge::Edge(string src, string dst)` -> use the pattern `Edge::Edge(const string& src, const strin&g dst)` - Saves copying objects

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is not like other functions in C++. A constructor's job is to initialize an object. In order to ensure the object gets initialized in a sensible way, all of the member objects (and base objects) need to be initialized. *This happens **before** the opening brace of the constructor body, so that everything is in a sensible state when you're in the constructor body.

To make sure this happens in the way you want, you can use an [*initializer list*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) (note that this term also refers to something else when initializing various containers; if you've heard the term before in relation to that, it's not what I'm discussing here). After the function signature, you put a colon, followed by each member of your class (in the same order they're declared in the class) and how you want to initialize it. For example, if you have the following `struct`

```
struct A {
    int i;
    char c;
    std::string s;
    A();
};
```

you can declare define your constructor as

```
A::A() : i{17}, c{'q'}, s{"Hello, mrb! Welcome to Stack Overflow"}
{
    // Nothing to do in the body of the constructor
}
```

That way, an `A` object's members are initialized to `17`, `'q'`, and a greeting *before the start of the function*, and are not initialized any other way.

---

Since you do not do this, the compiler instead uses the default constructor for the nodes. You then create other nodes inside the constructor body, and assign them to the nodes in your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
m_srcNode = Node(src);
m_dstNode = Node(dst);
```

Here, the two objects are first constructed with default constructor, then the overloaded constructed is called with `Node(src)` and `Node(dst)`. After that, the implicitly defined **copy assigner** is called to assign the temporary objects to `m_srcNode` and `m_dstNode`. Finally the temporary objects are destroyed.

If you want to avoid extra constructor calls, you can write a [**member initializer list**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
Edge::Edge(string src, string dst) : m_srcNode(src), m_dstNode(dst) {}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an example of a delegating constructor. Did you leave something out?

Comment: `Edge::Edge(string src, string dst) : m_srcNode(src), m_dstNode(dst) {}` is a fine example of using the Member Initializer list. It's hard to make an example of a delegating constructor for this one, but `Edge::Edge(string src) : Edge(src, "nowhere") {}` would be one. The one param constructor delegates to the two parameter constructor. This is a bad example because `Edge::Edge(string src, string dst = "nowhere") : m_srcNode(src), m_dstNode(dst) {}` seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: @user4581301 Looks like I had mistaken what a delegating constructor is.

Comment: Not a problem. Just swap the terms and lose that second link and your answer makes sense.

Comment: @user4581301 Done.